# Comparing strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

I am writing a Chrome extension, and in part of it, it checks a query against a JSON file. For some reason, when I compare the query and the JSON data using == , I keep getting weird results.

Here is the code:

```
    for(audio in newresponse.response)
    {
        console.log(song + " " + title);
        console.log(song == title);

        if(song == title)
        {
            console.log(newresponse.response[count].audio.url);
            chrome.tabs.create({url: newresponse.response[count].audio.url})
            break;
        }
        count++
    }
```

Here is the console:

```
tillimgonefeatwizkhalifa tillimgoneprodbystargate2o11
false
tillimgonefeatwizkhalifa tinietempahfeatwizkhalifatillimgone
false
tillimgonefeatwizkhalifa tillimgone
false
tillimgonefeatwizkhalifa tillimgonenew2011
false
http://cs4665.vkontakte.ru/u118769803/audio/d16ce7acd718.mp3
```

Why does the `if` statement result as true, when it obviously should not?

Comment: Nice spot @T.J., this code is clearly not the code producing that output...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That last line, with the URL, must be coming from other code, not from the quoted code.

In fact, that output doesn't match the code at all. In your code, nothing ever changes `song` or `title` **at all**, so we should just be seeing the same data repeated for as many enumerable properties as there are in `newresponse.response` (since the `for` loop will repeat for that many iterations).

So I think the answer here is: It isn't. The output you're referring to is from an earlier run with different code, or from code in another location in your page, etc.

But for the record, `==` will compare strings for equality, and it will do so reliably, so if you get `false` when logging, the `if` statement's body will not be run.

`==` does type coercion, which sometimes you want and sometimes you don't. For instance `1 == "1"` is `true`. If you want to compare strings for both type and content (e.g., so a string only ever matches a string and not a number coerced into a string), use `===`. E.g.:

```
var a, b;

a = 1;
b = "1";

display("a == b? " + (a == b));   // true
display("a === b? " + (a === b)); // false
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/owuno5)